# Помогите с задачей расчета электрической цепи матричным методом

Tags: алгоритм, схемотехника

В своей программе я составляю электрическую цепь с различными элементами и их параметрами (сопротивления , напряжения, ёмкость, индукция,...) и хочу правильно составить матрицу смежности для узлов схемы. Добавляю веса между узлами. Нашел библиотеку MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra которая вроде решает матричным методом уравнения Кирхгоффа. Но я не уверен в правильности составления матицы. Какие конкретные правила существуют для этого? Может надо использовать матрицу инцидентности ?

Comment: и правило составления вектора напряжений , видимо.